# How to force download text files from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I have a test.txt file stored in an S3 bucket and when i click on "Open", i want it to get downloaded but it is opening in the browser itself. I have tried setting Content-disposition to attachment but it did not work. Is there any way to force download text and json files from S3?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually headers are case sensitive. I'm not sure if S3 treats all versions of a header the same or not, but if you are using "Content-disposition" as written in this post, then you should try using "Content-Disposition" so the first letter of both words are capital. https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/1172-how-do-i-force-files-to-download-in-amazon-s3

Comment: I selected the meta-data from the AWS console itself. It is Content-Disposition and attachment. Sorry for the above case.

Comment: No problem, I wasn't sure if you had selected it or if you set it through the CLI.

Comment: The content is displayed in the browser itself though meta data is added.

Comment: I just tried it out with one of my buckets. Looks like if you click on "Open" it will force it to open inline. The content disposition is specific to the Object URL found for the S3 Object

Comment: The file is uploaded by Person A, i am creating a presigned url and giving it to Person B. So when Person B uses the url, it needs to get downloaded.

Comment: Did you solve it eventually?

Answer (score 1):

When you click `Open` in the S3 console, it sends `response-content-disposition=inline` to S3 which overwrites whatever `Content-Disposition` set on the object to `inline`. `Content-Disposition: inline` indicates that the content of this file can be displayed inside the Web page. This is why setting `Content-Disposition` won't work in this case.

If you need to download the file (instead of opening it in the web page) from the S3 console, you can either

- click `Open`
- on the new popup page, right click and choose `Save as ...`

Or

- click `Download as` in the S3 web console

Comment: The file is uploaded by Person A, i am creating a presigned url and giving it to Person B. So when Person B uses the url, it needs to get downloaded.

Comment: Have you tried using the presigned URL already? Like jelly said, if you click on Open then it will open the file inline, however by clicking download as, a presigned url, or the object url, it will work as an attachment by default.

Comment: I did not copy the complete url properly to the browser. Thank you, it worked.

Comment: Is there anyway i can force download without setting meta data? Like passing any attribute during the formation of presigned url?